# Can't set default value for form data in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask route, defined like this:

```
@app.route('/test/', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    number = request.form.get('my_number', 555) # number == ''
    return str(number)
```

If I make a POST request to `/test/` with `my_number` empty/missing, I expect the local variable `number` to be set to `555` (the default). Instead, `number` is an empty string `''`.

The only way I'm able to get the default value to be respected (`number == 555`) is to use `or` like this:

```
@app.route('/test/', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    number = request.form.get('my_number') or 555 # number == 555
    return str(number)
```

Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Can you please show what’s in the request.form?

Comment: The first code example uses "my_number" as the form variable. The second uses "number". Are you sure both examples are referencing the correct form variable?

Comment: @TheCoolah that was a typo on my part (in writing the example), but I can confirm the variables are the same in my tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that for your input, `request.form.get('number')` is always retrieving an empty string. Because there is something to retrieve, it never uses the default value even if you pass it as the second parameter.

`or`, however, treats `''` as false, so it will pick `555`. (see "Using or With Common Objects" https://realpython.com/python-or-operator/)

This implies that whenever you are accessing this url, the form you are posting has an entry for "number".